# Proper way/pattern to initialize objects in a container

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, initialization

I have a templated container `World`, that holds `Object`s. `World` is a workflow executed on `Object`s.

Normally I constructed `Object`s with the default constructor, but now I need to provide some parameters from the run-time.

My problem is finding a good and clean way to make `World` initialize `Object`s with given values.

**Proposed solution 1**

For now I have created a kind of `Init` object, that holds values needed for initialization of an `Object`, in the `main.cpp` I set it up and within the constructor of the `Object` I pass it to the instance of `Init` to perform initialization. It look something like this:

Object.h:

```
class Object; //forward declaration
struct Init {
  void Initialize(Object& object);
  int property1;
  double property2;
  string property3;
};

class Object{
 static Init init;
public:
 Object(){
   init.Initialize(*this);
 }
};
```

This way `World` does not need to have any knowledge on the construction of the `Object` and can just use a default constructor.

I somehow dislike this solution as overly complex and I am looking for something better.

**Q1**. Is this a good solution, and does this have a name (perhaps it's a design pattern, or antipattern)?

**Proposed solution 2**

I was thinking that I could pass-through the parameters needed to construct an `Object`, through some `World::init_objects` method. I believe this is possible since c++11. The `init_objects` method could be a variadic template that constructs the objects.

Proposed example:

```
template<typename Object>
class World {
  std::vector<Object> _internal_container;
  size_t _size;
public:
  World(size_t size) : _size(size) { _internal_container.reserve(_size); };

  template<typename... Args>
  init_objects(const Args&... args){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i) _internal_container.emplace_back( Object(args) );
  }
}
```

This way I don't have an extra object, and `World` also does not need to know anything about `Object` internal structure. `main.cpp` needs to call `init_objects` instead of setting up the `Object::init` instance.

**Q2**. Is such approach feasible, or has any major drawbacks? (I think I like it better, but maybe it is a bad idea that will hit a wall soon.)

**Q3**. Is there a better way to do it, that I did not think of. Maybe it is a simple problem with a go-to design pattern/implementation.

I think that my proposed solutions are not mutually exclusive, but I want to clean up my messy code, and choose a good, clean and nice code practice to pick up and stick to it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, actually I thought so initially... but I need to initialize a set of objects, and `std::forward` can perform a move, if it did, the next object could be initialized with an empty argument. So I think I cannot use the goodness of `std::forward`. But perhaps, I can use `emplace_back(args...)` if such syntax works. I think there is no difference, the Object will get constructed and moved anyways with emplace.

Comment: I don't think it can move since args are passed by a const reference. But if it does nothing, it shouldn't be there. The `...` must be there though. Also there's a colon missing before member initialization of `World` constructor.

Comment: I'm somewhat failing to see the point of `_size` if `_internal_container.capacity()` is synonymous after construction.

Comment: @user2079303 I think I could drop `const`, I want to possibly mimic the exact signature of the underlying constructor. I cannot use forward, because actual move would destroy the argument for rest of the objects.

Comment: @luk32 yes you can use move. declare a local object initialized with a move-constuction, then use *that* for replication.

Comment: @WhozCraig This is a valid point, it got redundant after simplifying the code. But it is not a big deal. I can edit it. But it does not change anything. I can change the code to use move. But it is used anyways there. Would introduction of a local object improve anything? Also please note it is just a proposed solution I want to know if using variadic templates and forwarding parameters to constructor is a good way. I can post it to code review later to polish the code.

Comment: That depends on the object class itself. it shouldn't matter as far as I can see, but its waaaay to late for me to be seeing anything right now =P

Comment: @luk32 sorry, I meant that the forward proposed by Jarod42 shouldn't be there if the params are const references. How about this (without the for loop): `_internal_container.resize(_size, {std::forward<Args>(args)...});` and change the declaration to: `init_objects(Args&&... args)`. You could then also get rid of the `reserve` in constructor.

Comment: Solution 3. Expose `emplace_back` of the underlying container (essentialy the same as `init_objects` of solution 2, minus the loop).

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is the Prototype Pattern where you start with one object that has the properties you want, then all objects created after are clones of the original prototype. The drawback of course being that someone somewhere has to create the first prototype.

Comment: No one uses `std::generate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q1.** Is this a good solution, and does this have a name (perhaps it's a design pattern, or antipattern)?

Yes. This is (more or less) the factory object pattern (though in the canonical example of Factory Object implementation, objects do not "know" what a factory is - there is no static reference to the factory in objects).

> **Q2.** Is such approach feasible, or has any major drawbacks? (I think I like it better, but maybe it is a bad idea that will hit a wall soon.)

The solution is feasible. One drawback is the way you implement the template on arguments/values to be set in the object.

Consider this implementation instead:

```
template<typename Object>
class World {
    std::vector<Object> objects;
    // size_t _size; // << size removed
public:
    World(size_t size) : objects(size) // use default constructor 
    {}

    template<typename P> // << changed here
    void apply(P predicate) { // << change here
        std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), predicate); // << and here
    }
};
```

Client code:

```
World w{10}; // create 10 objects with default values
w.apply([](object& o) { o.set_xyz(10); o.set_yyy(20); });
```

With this solution, you can use `apply` in a modular way (you can inject initialization or anything else really).

As a side note, also consider creating a World object based on an already constructed vector of objects, using a factory function (for the World, not for the objects inside). This would eliminate the need for extra initialization of objects (i.e. it would not affect the public interface of the world) and turn World into an exception-safe object (which may still require the `apply` method above, for other purposes):

```
template<typename O> class World {
    std::vector<O> objects;
public:
    World(std::vector<O> obj) : objects{std::move(obj)} {}
    // eventually define apply function here
};

template<typename O, typename... Args>
World<O> make_world(size_t size, const Args&... args){
    std::vector<O> objects{size};
    for(auto& o: objects)
    { /* set arguments here */ }
    return World<O>{std::move(objects)};
}
```

**Edit**: Concrete make_world example, without requiring default constructor for the encapsulated objects:

```
struct Length { int length; Length(int l) : length{l} {} };

World<Length> make_length_world(size_t size, int default_length)
{
    std::vector<Length> values;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; ++index)
        values.emplace_back(default_length);
    return World<Length>{std::move(values)};
}

struct Person {
    std::string first_name; std::string last_name;
    Person(std::string first, std::string last)
    : first_name{std::move(first)}, last_name{std::move(last)} {}
};


World<Person> make_robert_paulson_world(size_t size)
    // "his name is Robert Paulson"
    // so don't pass name as parameter
{
    std::vector<Person> values;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; ++index)
        values.emplace_back("Robert", "Paulson");
    return World<Person>{std::move(values)};
}
```

Comment: I design the `World`, and my point is to make the rest client-friendly. I was thinking about your last solution too. But I would like not to make client prepare the container when every object just needs to be initialized in the same way. The problem is I would like not to require `Object` to be default constructible, this is why I proposed passing through the constructor parameters. But I do like the design of your ideas very much. On the side note, am I right that actually all three options can be implemented and supported at the same time?

Comment: @luk32, the make_world factory function is just an example implementation. A real-world implmentation doesn't have to require default initialization (and it will probably vary with the concrete type of `O` - if it will be templated by `O` at all). You could have a non-templated `make_widget_world` that creates a `World<Widget>`, without introducing extra constraints or dependencies in anything else (i.e. if you add already constructed `Widget` instances to the vector, you won't need Widget to be default constructible).

Comment: Also (on top of my previous comment), yes, all three solutions can be implemented at the same time. Regarding constraints on the object type, my proposed solution is a design best-practice ("you should pass _already constructed_ objects into a constructor and if those require extra initialization steps, you should put the extra steps in a factory method" outside the class). This encourages design to explicitly define construction dependencies, reduces duplicate code and eases implementations that offer weak exception guarantees (and exception-safety).

Comment: I will probably end up with implementing support for both options - argument pass-through, and `apply`-method. `apply` is more versatile, and pass-through does not require object to be default constructible. I will also implement passing whole container at a latter stage. I do not want to do it now, because it is more complicated and requires some (serious) refactoring. For now I want the `World` to be able to handle simple cases on its own, so the entry level for the framework is low. Later if User wants to construct objects beforehand (your proposed solution), so be it, I will support it.

Comment: @luk32, see my edit/example (in the answer above): Extracting the construction of the objects into a factory method for the vector allows you to avoid imposing any restrictions in the encapsulated objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your first example is basically making a Factory Class. In your case it is a factory struct but basically it serves the same purpose, i.e. it is a class that knows how to build `Object`. It is unusual though (and unnecessary) for the class itself to have a dependency on its own factory. A more usual use would be for you to inject a concrete type of the factory into `World`. This can be either a traditional injection (as a parameter) or a template injection.

```
template<typename FactoryType>
class World {
private:
  std::vector<Object> _internal_container;
public:
  World(size_t objectCount){
    FactoryType factory; // of course you could store this in a field if you need.
    for(size_t i = 0; i < objectCount; ++i) 
      _internal_container.emplace_back( factory.getDefaultObject() );
  }
}
```

All that said I think that your variadic template solution looks interesting. The only downside I can see is that the error codes might be hard to understand. If someone passes the wrong types to the template it could result in an obscure error. No more than other template related errors though.

In terms of other methods of doing this, I suppose you could also inject a functor of some kind to deal with the building, but basically all of these methods all have the same underlying principle, to remove the logic of how to build from the class USING the object.
The most important thing once you have this separation is that your code is clear and maintainable.